# How to shuffle cards - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, shuffle, iife, randomized-algorithm

I'm trying to make a card matching game in JavaScript where every time the user starts the game, the cards shuffle. If they flip two of the same cards the get a point added to their score. I have the card matching aspect working using a data framework on each card div, but this immediately invoked shuffle card function I've added isn't working. Thank you in advance!

JavaScript of Shuffling the Cards:

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".the-card");

(function shuffle() {
  cards.forEach(card => {
    let randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
    card.style.order = randomPos;
  });
})();
```

HTML of Each Card(16 in total):

```
<div class="main-card-container">
<div class="the-card" data-framework="twoofhearts">

   <div class="the-back card-face">
      <img src="./images/cardback.png" class="flipped-card" 
   </div>
   <div class="the-front card-face">
      <img src="./images/img-1.png" class="unflipped-card" 
   </div>

</div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming you create all cards ahead of time, and collect them as an array in JS, this answer may be pertinent to what you're trying to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: make sure that class="main-card-container" has display: flex set.

and seems like your shuffle function can return repeated orders.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm which runs in `O(n)`, so there's no way to do it faster.

It's quite simple really:

```js
var inOrder = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function fisherYatesShuffle(array){
  for(let i = array.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
    const newPosition = Math.floor((i + 1) * Math.random());
    const temp = array[newPosition];
    array[newPosition] = array[i];
    array[i] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(fisherYatesShuffle(inOrder));
```

On a side note: how random it really is does depend on how good your random numbers are. [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) is not cryptographically secure i.e. not all numbers are equally likely to be generated. If you want that you need to use [`Crypto.getRandomValues()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues). `Math.random()` is however much faster and should do for the randomness required in a game.

For more information on randomness see this blog post [Baeldung CS - Understanding Randomness](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/randomness).